# Adding self-drawn lines to txt-file with existing line coordinates

Tags: java

I have a program drawing lines forming a map over the coordinates and i have added a method so I can draw lines over the already existing lines from coordinates given in a txt file. My question is how to make it possible to add the lines i am drawing myself to the txt-file, and thereby saving my drawn lines next time i run my program?
Ps. I'm using intelliJ.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html

Comment: This may be unhelpful if you are required to do this in a text file, but SVG is perfect for this. Draw once, cache and use repeatedly. Here's a tool that could possibly help: https://github.com/jfree/jfreesvg

Comment: Please go thru the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
 and improve the quality of your question for more users to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try append those coordinates to the file with the FileWriter class. To read it back just use FileReader.

And I advise you to check the Oracle Tutorials on IO operations.